# Artifactory : Error : Ping failed since server state is blocked

Tags: azure, artifactory

I have installed artifactory-HA on two nodes and load balancer is configured to probe artifactory's health in frequent intervals. Ping fails. System is built on Azure. Both, artifactory and nginx services are up and running.

Contents of $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log

```
2018-10-26 18:59:22,633 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [ERROR] (o.a.r.r.s.PingResource:76) - Ping failed since the server state is blocked
```

Contents of $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/request.log

```
20181026185727|1|REQUEST|<ip>|anonymous|GET|/api/system/ping|HTTP/1.1|503|0
20181026185732|2|REQUEST|<ip>|anonymous|GET|/api/system/ping|HTTP/1.1|503|0
```

Request is coming in. But, I couldn't make out as why this error is happening. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you sure you have valid licenses installed on both nodes?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, it turned out to be a license issue.    As mentioned by @DarthFennec in the comments above    Removing the expired Trial license and adding the new license allowed the curl ping command to succeed.

`/usr/bin/curl -f --insecure -u admin:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type:application/json' http://artent-01.mydomain:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping`